# Use different versions of Firebase and Google Play Services in same Android project?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-play-services, build.gradle

Is it possible to use different versions of Firebase and Google Play Services in project? I need to use 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+' and 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1' in the same project. Now it create version conflict.

Is it possible to exclude 'com.google.android.gms'?

Comment: Is there something forcing you to use `play-services:6.1.x`?  It is [more than 3 years old](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases).

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not. In order to solve this, as specified in the offical documentation on how to [Add Firebase to Your Android Project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup), in `Prerequisites` section is said:

> A device running Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) or newer, and Google Play services **12.0.1** or higher.

So in order to solve this, change the version of your Google Play services to last version (`12.0.1`).